# Using FileSystemObject (VBA) with filter

Tags: vba, filesystemobject

With my code I have to write a file name to search : "test.txt" . It works fine, returns as many as test.txt exist in the selected path.

I want it to work searching : "txt" and get all the .txt files in the selected path.

My code :

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fld As Folder

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim nDirs As Long, nFiles As Long, lSize As Currency
   Dim sDir As String, sSrchString As String
   sDir = InputBox("Type the directory that you want to search for", _
                   "FileSystemObjects example", "C:\")
   sSrchString = InputBox("Type the file name that you want to search for", _
                   "FileSystemObjects example", "")
  ' MousePointer = vbHourglass
  ' Label1.Caption = "Searching " & vbCrLf & UCase(sDir) & "..."
   lSize = FindFile(sDir, sSrchString, nDirs, nFiles)
  ' MousePointer = vbDefault
   MsgBox Str(nFiles) & " files found in" & Str(nDirs) & _
          " directories", vbInformation
   MsgBox "Total Size = " & lSize & " bytes"
End Sub

Private Function FindFile(ByVal sFol As String, sFile As String, _
   nDirs As Long, nFiles As Long) As Currency
   Dim tFld As Folder, tFil As File, FileName As String

   On Error GoTo Catch
   Set fld = fso.GetFolder(sFol)
   FileName = Dir(fso.BuildPath(fld.path, sFile), vbNormal Or _
                  vbHidden Or vbSystem Or vbReadOnly)
   While Len(FileName) <> 0
      FindFile = FindFile + FileLen(fso.BuildPath(fld.path, _
      FileName))
      nFiles = nFiles + 1
   '   List1.AddItem fso.BuildPath(fld.Path, FileName)  ' Load ListBox
      FileName = Dir()  ' Get next file
      DoEvents
   Wend
  ' Label1 = "Searching " & vbCrLf & fld.Path & "..."
   nDirs = nDirs + 1
   If fld.SubFolders.Count > 0 Then
      For Each tFld In fld.SubFolders
         DoEvents
         FindFile = FindFile + FindFile(tFld.Path, sFile, nDirs, nFiles)
      Next
   End If
   Exit Function
Catch:  FileName = ""
       Resume Next
End Function
```

**and a tip, I've found something like :**

```
For Each file In files
                    If Right(file, 3) = "pdf" Then
                        myMailItem.Attachments.Add CStr(file)
                        found = True
                    End If
```

But I couldn't get it working in my code.

Thanks!

Comment: `Dir()` accepts wildcards, so you can just use `Dir("C:\foldername\*.txt")` for example.

Comment: @TimWilliams How did you put that in a VBScript? Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Variable is undefined: 'Dir'

Comment: https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/dir-statement-in-vbscript.1804361/